# setting SelectParameters asp:ControlParameter for a CheckBox control

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, sqldatasource

I have a GridView that I'm trying to set up a filter based on the input to several controls (mostly TextBoxes) in a Panel.  I've done this elsewhere without the checkbox that I'm having difficulty with and it works great.  But now with this case I've got a checkbox that supplies info for the filter.

The checkbox looks like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="TicketClosed_ChBox" runat="server" Width="25px" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
```

In the select statement of the datasrouce I am building it as:

```
AND (RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(@TicketClosed, ''))) = '' OR TicketClosed LIKE '%' + @TicketClosed + '%') AND
```

Then in the  for the DataSource I'm linking in the textbox control with:

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="TicketClosed" ControlID="TicketClosed_ChBox" Type="Boolean" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
```

The problem with this is that it comes back saying "The data types varchar and bit are incompatible in the add operator."

I've tried flipping the ControlParameter to Byte and several other types but it still fails. I'm really not sure why I can't get this to fly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If I’m not mistaken, the `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` is only for data types of String.  A checkbox will always have a value and never be `NULL`.  Try deleting that part of the parameter and see if that works.